# Sync problems with S3 to EC2: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was working on a E-commerce project ( for study ) and wanted to sync my webfiles from S3 to EC2.

I used this command in the Linux SSH session:

> #6. download the FleetCart zip from s3 to the html directory on the ec2 instance

```
sudo aws s3 sync s3://deg-s3bucketwebfiles /var/www/html
```

Entering the command, I get the following error message:

> -- > fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

Not sure, what is wrong ? I checked that there's a directory /var/www/html but somehow the files cannot be sync across to EC2.

Appreciate any guide.

Thanks

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the advice. I have managed to trace the issue that the IAM ROLE S3 policy wasn't attached to the EC2 hence the credentials issues.  All solved. !

Answer (score 2):

`Unable to locate credentials` means that the `aws` command is unable to locate any credentials on the EC2 instance. The credentials are used to identify you to AWS so it knows that you are entitled to access the `deg-s3bucketwebfiles` bucket.

**Option 1: Use an IAM Role**

Since you are using an Amazon EC2 instance, the correct way to provide credentials to the instance is to associate an **IAM Role** to the instance. The role would need permission to access S3.

**Option 2: Use credentials from an IAM User**

Alternatively, you can use credentials associated with your **IAM User.** Go to the IAM Console, select your IAM User and go to the Security Credentials tab. You will find a **Create access key** button.

It will provide an **Access Key** and a **Secret Key**. The Access Key starts with `AKIA`, while the Secret Key is a long jumble of characters.

Once you have these credentials, run this command on the EC2 instance:

```
aws configure
```

Provide the credentials when prompted.

Comment: Thanks John for your advice. Let me look into this .